# Easy to read collection selection based on type table value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 site using SQL Server, Dapper.net. It has these models.

I have a Listing class:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public short ListingTypeId { get; set; }
public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }
public string Details { get; set; }
```

and a ListingType class:

```
public short Id { get; set; }
public string ListingTypeName { get; set; }
```

There are 20 listing types - and this number may change over time.

Let's say we add a "Movie" listing type. I would like to, say, get all listings with ListingTypeName = "Movie" - in easy to read code, that doesn't require a new method only for that.

If we assume ListingType Id = 21 for Movies - essentially I'm trying to execute SQL like this:

```
Select * From Listing Where ListingTypeID = 21
```

However, that is very unsemantic - even if we wrap this in a SelectMovies method in a repository - "21" is pretty meaningless.

I could select every row of the Listing table - and use LINQ to fish out the Movies - however, the table may be very large, and this wouldn't be performant.

I could use Enums synched up to the ListingType IDs in the database - and this would be very easy to read - eg:

```
var MovieListings = myRepo.Select(myEnum.Movie);
```

But generally, it's not a good idea to use those for changeable lists of items as they get out of sync and duplicate data in the databases. I don't want to do that.

Is it possible to create this in a way that has semantic easy to read code, without using enums or hard coding database Ids & using best practices?

Comment: Wndrr's answer doesn't solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
What I think you should do here is to add a uniqueness constraint on the `ListingTypeName` column in the database, so a `ListingType`'s name can't be duplicate. Maybe even replace the numeric Id with a text id if it doesn't hurt performances too hard (if you only have ~20 records it should be pretty okay).

In your question you mention repositories and I think they are a pretty good thing. In fact, they could even do a perfect job in your case ! Simply add a method to the repository that'd be `FindListingByTypeName(string name)` and it would internally look for the `ListingType` using its name, and then use the Id of the to retrieve the listings.

By the way, if you have to hard-code something like `Select * From Listing Where ListingTypeID = 21` you have a big design problem. This should come from a user interface to whom you'd display TypeNames and then map to the Type id.

Comment: In my example '21' would be a variable - I wouldn't literally have a hard coded value in there. A unique constraint in a database that is a string isn't good practice, so I don't find this ideal. I ended up using an Enum as listing types will almost never (maybe never) change - and if they did there would need to be code changes elsewhere so I deemed it OK. Thanks anyway.